# How to check whether the new line is created but not saved yet

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

Which FormDataSource method to use to determine that the record is not saved yet?

i.e.

[image]

I mean when my grid line is in this situation I want my mennuItemButton to throw the error.

Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check the RecId == 0, but in your case it would be simpler to set the NeedsRecord attribute of the menu item. This will disable the button if there is no active record.